Add target specific rustc flags when building "std"
I'm trying add a new target in rustc and I need to provide a separate search path to a directory which contains native artifacts (such as static libraries or crt*) that are needed for linking for the new target. During the bootstrapping of rustc, this should only be applied when building the libraries for the target (stage2), not when building the libraries for the host.
Since the config.toml configuration does not seem to allow per-target rustflags (where one could provide the search path via rustflags="-L <searchdir>"), I wonder if there's another way?
I'm open for either a way to express this...

in the x.py/config.toml build system of the rust repo, or
in the Cargo.toml in library/, or
any other idea how to achieve this

